# Metric with changing label

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager, victoriametrics, metricsql

I have a label called `managed` that it can be changed between `0` and `1` at anytime by the host machine. I have an alert that notifies when a metric is lagging behind by more than 90s.

However, it doesn't account for the `managed` label change so when the label changes, the alert would trigger but the server is fine. I have been trying several things but doesn't see a way to go forward. What I have atm:

```
(
   min(lag(load.load.shortterm{}[12h:]) keep_metric_names) by (fqdn) > 90s
)
+ on(fqdn) group_left(managed)
(
   0*lag(load.load.shortterm{}[12h:]) keep_metric_names
)
```

This will return 2 metrics with `managed = 1` and `managed = 0`. However, I need the latest `managed` label to return so I know whether to escalate it or not. Do anyone have any recommendations on how I can archive my desire behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [lag](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#lag) function is calculated independently per each time series returned from the given series_selector. When you have a dynamic label, you have only one time series at a time. It means when the label changes from 1 to 0 the time series with `managed=1` becomes stale (not updated anymore), and series with `managed=0` becomes active. The lag for the first time series will start to grow since it gets no updates anymore. This is what triggers your alert.

I suggest you to change the metric structure from `load.load.shortterm{managed="<state>"}` to `load.load.shortterm.managed{} <state>`. With this change, you'll always have only one time series and `lag` will work properly for it.